# Derived Get/Set Methods

Tags: c++

Imagine I have this code:

```
class A {
 public:
  void GetInt() { cout << number << endl; }
  void SetInt(int n) { number = n; }

 private:
  int number = 0;
};

class B : public A {
 public:
  void GetInt() { cout << number << endl; }

 private:
  int number = 0;
};

int main() {
  B b;
  b.SetInt(5);
  b.GetInt(); // Prints 0, needs to be 5

  return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to make `SetInt()` changing `B.number` without implementing it in `B`? Imagine I have 500 derived classes from `A`, and they set their number in the same `{ number = n; }`. Do I have to implement the same `SetInt()` method 500 times?

Comment: why does `B` have a member `number` in the first place? Note that together with the one from the base `B` has two `number` members. Do you need both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way to get what you ask for is this:

```
class A {
 public:
  void GetInt() { cout << number << endl; }
  void SetInt(int n) { number = n; }

 private:
  int number = 0;
};

class B : public A {
    // don't hide methods inherited from A
    // don't add members that are already present (as private member of A)
};

int main() {
  B b;
  b.SetInt(5);
  b.GetInt(); // Prints 5

  return 0;
}
```

Private members are inherited, they just cannot be accessed directly. Though as `A` does provide public accessors, `B` has acess to `A::number` via the setter from `A`.

*PS* A method called `Get___` should actually return something, not just print the value on the screen.

Comment: Yeah, sounds reasonable. But what if A was abstract with `virtual int GetInt() { return name;}` and `virtual void SetInt(int n) = 0`? In this case `SetInt()` isn't able to change number in `A`, and I need to override `GetInt()`, which leads to my problem.

Comment: @akolechko you should ask the question you actually want to ask ;). There is nothing virtual or abstract in your code.

Comment: @akolechko anyhow in that case it is still not clear why you want `A::number` and `B::number`. `B` does not need two `number` members, it should be `protected` in `A` if you need direct access in `B`

Comment: @akolechko The point is, you cannot access private members in derived classes, no matter whether you make functions virtual or whatever.

Comment: @akolechko and another important point is: You probably do not need `B::number`, when you already have `A::number`

Comment: Hm, yes, I just rewrote the code and it works fine. Affected by lack of sleep I guess. Big thanks, you helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

No, `0` is the correct result. In your `class B` you create a whole new member `B::number` which is independent from `A:::number`. So when you run `A::SetInt`, that member function changes `A::number` and when you run `B::GetInt`, that function accesses `A::number` which was never set to `5`.

Try not to have members in derived types that have the same name as a member in the base class. All it does is create confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In case you really want each derived class to yield and handle its own value in terms of class hierachy separation - which I'd find at least questionable at all in terms of design and problem solution approach - you cannot avoid a minimum amount of code duplication for each derivation. At least you need the member access itself to be duplicated. There are some template/macro tricks to circumvent code explosions here (generic member instrusion), but since I really don't think, that this is what you want to achieve, I do not go into details for now.

Otherwise, idclev 463035818's answer is the way to go.